# Efficient algorithm to divide time intervals as equally as possible

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to do the following:

Given a few dates, say, A, B, and C, I'd like to

1. Partition (C - A) into N number of intervals
2. One of the intervals must have B as its bound
3. The intervals should be as close to being equal as possible

Can anyone suggest an efficient algorithm to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: is N given or calculated?

Comment: Convert them to milli seconds and divide by N?

Comment: Hi, N is given, a fixed integer.

Comment: well what if B much closer to A than C, but you are given a non-granular N, like 2? what is your expected output?

Comment: "As equal as possible" is quite vague... There are lots of things you can mean by this. I.e., you can divide in equal parts and then move the border closest to B, for one thing.

Comment: What is the minimum partition size?

Comment: If one interval has B as its bound, wouldn't there necessarily be another interval (on the other side of B) that has B as its bound?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example:

```
A = 0
B = 45
C = 100
N = 10 interval  (10 interval = 11 bound)
```

1: Find the ratio X/N which is the closest to the ratio AB / AC

```
4/10 < 45/100 5/10
we will take X = 4 in this example (the result will vary depending on how you round it.
```

2: Set the bound number taken from previous calculation to have bound from A to B

```
A to B:
  Interval number 4 (from previous value)
  Bound number 5
  Average interval length is (45-0) / 4 = 11
Bound 0 = 0
Bound 1 = 11
Bound 2 = 22
Bound 3 = 33 
Bound 4 = 45
```

3: Set the bound number taken from previous calculation to have bound from B to C

```
B to C:
  Interval number 6 (the rest)
  Bound number 7
  Average interval length is (100 - 45) / 6 = 9
Bound 4 = 45
Bound 5 = 54
Bound 6 = 63
Bound 7 = 72
Bound 8 = 81 
Bound 9 = 90
Bound 10 = 100
```